# Jar Exception in java

Tags: java, jar-signing

I am getting **java.lang.SecurityException** and **java.util.jar.JarException** , when trying to use the **cryptix-jce-provider.jar** . It says that the JAR has unsigned entries - cryptix/jce/ElGamalKey.class

how can i resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [cryptix](http://www.cryptix.org/) website.  The certificate used to sign cryptix jar files have expired.  Hence the warning. Workarounds are in [this discussion](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=4A4B8A6E.1020507@orbaker.com&forum_name=cryptix-users).

Comment: actually I am having a unsigned cryptix jar. Since the JAR is not the signed one , I am gettting the exception. When I ran the command "jarsigner -verify -certs  cryptix-jce-provider.jar "  , I got the following output, " jar is unsigned. (signatures missing or not parsable)" . Is there a way to bypass the signature verification ?